# Why findbyidandupdate returns `null` value in Mongoose 6

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I use nodejs v18, Express v4 and Mongoose v6. I try to update a document but this line returns null.

```js
const doc = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(userId, newUser, { new: true })
// doc is null
```

`newUser` have two properties: `email` and `password`

I tried to delete my index 'unique' in my MongoDB... but nothing better...
I think, this line is correct. The issue comes from another part of my code but I really have no idea.

Comment: make sure `newUser` is not null, other reason might be if userId does not exists

Comment: newUser is not null. I check the userId is a String type and exists. When, I send a request PUT and try to update, it deletes my document for the userId.

Comment: Can you try to `console.log(userId)` and add it to the question? Maybe it's incorrectly passed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found a solution. I do not really understand what it happened with the email. When I try to update without the email it works. But with the email, `findbyidandupdate` returns null and remove my doc. I will test my code know.